# Not namespaced, classmap loaded package required from composer makes php throw Class not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use this package: github.com/pagseguro/php (actually a fork in my repositories because of some necessary changes) in a Laravel app.

It is not namespaced at all and it autoloads using classmap:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["source/PagSeguroLibrary"]
},
```

vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php has all the classes, for example:

```
'PagSeguroPaymentRequest' => $vendorDir . '/hfingler/php/source/PagSeguroLibrary/domain/PagSeguroPaymentRequest.class.php',
```

The init class (`PagSeguroLibrary::init();`) works, but as soon as I need another class I get an error:

```
$paymentRequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PagSeguroPaymentRequest' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
```

This works in my localhost environment, but doesn't in my remote server. Both have the same files (using `git pull` and `composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction --no-dev --no-progress`) and I ran `composer dump-autoload` in both.

Any idea? Thanks.

edit:
 Fixed it by running most composer commands (status, clearcache, diagnose) then removing the package from `composer.json`, updating, adding the package and running update again.

Comment: Does this `/hfingler/php/source/PagSeguroLibrary/domain/PagSeguroPaymentRequest.class.php` file exist? Make sure the capitalisations matches as well.

Comment: Are you 200% sure? `ls -la /...//hfingler/php/source/PagSeguroLibrary/domain/PagSeguroPaymentRequest.class.php` runs well?

Comment: Copied `hfingler/php/source/PagSeguroLibrary/domain/PagSeguroPaymentRequest.class.php` from autoload_classmap.php, cd into `vendor`, `cat hfingler/php/source/PagSeguroLibrary/domain/PagSeguroPaymentRequest.class.php` shows the file.

Comment: "Found in eval()'d code" - are you sure you want to use `eval()`? Or do you do it yourself? A little bit more code that demonstrates the problem would be nice, i.e. at least a two liner: 1. Include Composer autoloader, 2. Instantiate the class that doesn't work.

Comment: eval is because I was using laravel artisan's tinker command, it just pops a interactive php cli. Inside the actual code same thing happens, class not found.

Comment: And can you show some actual code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I've already solved this, more details in question. There is only one line of code that was throwing the error: `$paymentRequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();`.