# Laravel 4.2 and PayPal SDK

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the following error:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found'
```

Here is my Controller code:

```
<?php

use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

class PaypalPaymentController extends BaseController {

    private $_api_context;

    public function __construct() { 

        // setup PayPal api context
        $paypal_conf = Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);

    }
```

I'm not sure what the Service Provider needs to be, either... could someone fill in that blank at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed the package from composer on a L5 installation and it worked, so here's what I think will help you:

If you're not using composer, remove everything related to paypal and use it, it helps.. a lot.

Remove the paypal package from `composer.json`, `composer update`, `composer dumpautoload`, `php artisan cache:clear`.

Add the package again, I did it with `"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "1.3.*"`. `composer update`.

Test it using `php artisan tinker`, like this: `new PayPal\Rest\ApiContext()`, should return some blue lines describing the object.

I SERIOUSLY believe this is a composer problem, I had the same problem with another payment package, but nothing was namespaced, they used `classmap` loading, paypal uses psr-0. This was the question:  [Not namespaced, classmap loaded package required from composer makes php throw Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218045/not-namespaced-classmap-loaded-package-required-from-composer-makes-php-throw-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [composer](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation-Composer) to download the PayPal-PHP-SDK, you would need to add the `include` statement to add all the classes, as shown below:

```
// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files and classes to your autoloader
require '<location to vendor directory>/vendor/autoload.php';
```

If you used [direct download](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation-Direct-Download), you need to add include, with this path:

```
// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files and classes to your autoloader
require '<location to PayPal-PHP-SDK directory>/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Hey Jay, thanks... but are you sure I need a require statement with Laravel?

Comment: So, if you use composer for downloading laravel, when you added paypal-php-sdk, it would automatically update the autoload.php with these classes. However, if not, you may need to explicitly set that.

Comment: Can you print your project layout ? That would help figure this out. If on a linux or mac machine, you can do so by `tree -L 4`

Comment: I'm honestly about to give up... I've been trying to get this package to work for months.

Comment: I think it is something really small that is causing this error. I am not proficient in Laravel, however, paypal sdk is supported with laravel, and is used quite frequently with laravel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74309/discussion-between-jay-patel-paypal-and-dcolumbus).